# using SELECT INTO with multiple rows

Tags: sql, insert

This is re 
I want to create a table using the results of a query by utilizing SELECT INTO.
The syntax

```
SELECT *
INTO Persons_Backup
FROM Persons
```

is very close to what I want to achieve, with the difference being that I want the FROM to use a query as source.

My situation is a bit more complicated than these simple examples.

I need to create a table and insert multiple rows at the same time. If I could (I can't) use a previously created table the statement would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO Person_Backup12 (Col1, Col2, Col3)
Select 1, 'a','2001-01-01 12:00'
UNION ALL
Select 83, 'z','2011-09-30 13:27'
UNION ALL
Select 777, 'k','1997-04-25 09:27'
```

Can I do that while creating a table at the same time?

Comment: If you're moving large amounts of data then `SELECT INTO` is not the most efficient way of doing this. If possible, rather follow the `CREATE TABLE` `INSERT INTO` approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put your query into a common table expression or derived table then `SELECT ... INTO` from that.

```
;WITH cte (Col1, Col2, Col3) AS
(
Select 1, 'a','2001-01-01 12:00'
UNION ALL
Select 83, 'z','2011-09-30 13:27'
UNION ALL
Select 777, 'k','1997-04-25 09:27'
)
SELECT *
INTO NewTable
FROM cte
```

In this case you would probably need some explicit casts to get the desired column datatype (`datetime` rather than `char` etc.)

Comment: You are a star! thanks. I did not even consider using a CTE. Nice!

Answer (score 4):

A `CTE` shouldn't be necessary:

```
Select 1 as 'Col1', 'a' as 'Col2','2001-01-01 12:00' as 'Col3'
INTO Person_Backup12
UNION ALL
Select 83, 'z','2011-09-30 13:27'
UNION ALL
Select 777, 'k','1997-04-25 09:27'
```

Worked fine for me in 2008 r2.

Comment: @Martin - a lot of folks I work with use `SELECT INTO` frequently so I know more than I want to about it :)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, yes:

```
SELECT *
INTO Persons_Backup
FROM 
(
    Select 1 AS Col1, 'a' AS Col2,'2001-01-01 12:00' AS Col3
    UNION ALL
    Select 83 AS Col1, 'z' AS Col2,'2011-09-30 13:27' AS Col3
    UNION ALL
    Select 777 AS Col1, 'k' AS Col2,'1997-04-25 09:27' AS Col3
) AS SomeQuery
```