# SQL INSERT INTO with prefined data and also a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

So I found this link [using SELECT INTO with multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566226/using-select-into-with-multiple-rows) and some others but I didn't feel like it answered my question.

So I need to INSERT INTO a query like this

```
INSERT INTO sampleTable (toUserid, blah, lah, blah)
VALUES 
(x, blah, lah, blah),
(y, blah, lah, blah),
(z, blah, lah, blah),
(p, blah, lah, blah),
(r, blah, lah, blah),
(v, blah, lah, blah)
```

The x,y,z,p,r,v are the Userid's that I find from a select query that only pulls in the userid's I need. What I've been doing thus far is just use Excel to concatenate the column of user into its own row that I have above then just copy/paste it over.

I'd like to not be dependent on Excel. I'd like to use SQL for something like this...

```
INSERT INTO sampleTable (toUserid, blah, lah, blah)
VALUES 
(SELECT userid from xtable, blah, lah blah)
```

I know that's probably not what it would look like but I hope I've clearly expressed what I need. Thanks

Comment: `INSERT INTO SampleTable(toUserID, blah, lah, blah) SELECT userid, blah, lah, blah FROM xtable`

Comment: If you use a `SELECT` to provide the values for your `INSERT`, you **must not** specify a `VALUES` keyword, and your `SELECT` must provide exactly the number of values (as columns) that the `INSERT` expects. In your case, your `INSERT` expects four values - but the `SELECT` only shows one column ....

Comment: Marc, thanks for the clarification. So I expect my select subquery to pull in about 50 different userids. So does that mean I would need 50 different lines then for each userid? My aim is to do this in one query.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot understand what your problem is.

```
INSERT INTO sampleTable (toUserid, blah, lah, blah)
VALUES 
(SELECT userid from xtable, blah, lah blah)
```

this query is malformed, as it's syntax is

```
INSERT INTO sampleTable (toUserid, blah, lah, blah)
(SELECT userid from xtable, blah, lah blah)
```

Can you please tell me what your doubt is actualy?

Comment: But if I'm pulling in like 50 userids, do I really only need to do (SELECT userid from xtable, blah, lah blah)?

Comment: all the results from (SELECT userid from xtable, blah, lah blah) will be inserted. If you need to filter it you need to include the filter clauses on the select query, like join or where..

Comment: So say that the query SELECT userid from xtable pulls in a column with the userids as x,y,z,p,r,v... then doing the query you gave would be equivalent to  INSERT INTO sampleTable (toUserid, blah, lah, blah)
VALUES 
(x, blah, lah, blah),
(y, blah, lah, blah),
(z, blah, lah, blah),
(p, blah, lah, blah),
(r, blah, lah, blah),
(v, blah, lah, blah)?

Comment: correct, just go ahead and try it yoursefl, test the feature, you can use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to do your sql query tests

Answer (score 1):

Just move your other values into your inner `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO sampleTable (toUserid, blah, blah, blah)
SELECT userid, blah, blah blah from xtable
```

Comment: So... the blah blah blah is not coming from xtable, they're just predefined text that I'll hardcode into the query. The only thing I'm pulling in from xtable are the userids... which would be multiple

Comment: @user3005697 - that's fine - you can "select" constants:  `SELECT userid, 1, 2, 'ABCD' from xtable`

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
INSERT INTO sampleTable (toUserid, blah, lah, blah)
VALUES
(
  SELECT  users_ids.userid,
          data.blah,
          data.lah,
          data.bah
  FROM table_with_users users
    JOIN table_with_data data
      ON <something>
)
```